# upload image with fetch API after user pick one

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I need to upload an image as profile photo to the server after user select preferred photo from gallery.
I'll explain the scenario here:
first user select preferred photo, I need to call an API to send user Id and it returns to me another Id for the photo and after that I need to call media upload API and send user id, selected photo, folder name which is users and file extension. here's how I implement this:

```js
  const userData = useSelector(state => state.user.userData)

//alow for access to the gallery
  const allowAccess = async () => { 
    if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
      const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      } else {
        pickImage()
          .then((imageUri) => {
            getUploadId(userData.id)
              .then(
                uploadMedia(userData.id, imageUri)
              )
          })
      }
    }
  }

  const getUploadId = (userId) => {
    return axios
      .post('**api_url**', {
        "id": userId
      })
      .then(response => {
        // response.data is the products
        const uploadId = response.data
        console.log('this is upload id', uploadId)
        return uploadId
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // error.message is the error message
        console.log(error.message)
      })
  }

  const uploadMedia = (userId, imageFile) => {
    return axios
      .post('**api_url**'
        , {
          "fileName": userId,
          "FormFile": imageFile,
          "FolderName": "Users",
          "FileExtension": '.jpg'
        })
      .then(response => {
        const res = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // error.message is the error message
        console.log(error.message)
      })
  }

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    const imageUri = result.uri
    return imageUri
  };
```

the status code that media upload gave to me is 500, how can I handle that? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: using `return` in async function is not a valid statement, because async functions will always return a `Promise`, you need to nest your api call functions inside each other's callback

Comment: @VáclavRyska Umm..like how?

Comment: didn't check the integrity if this valid in terms of syntax or variables, but generally should look like this: https://pastebin.com/FkAXkwMn